# Not sure how to return a phrase after a match, and also include a conditional clause

Tags: regex, r

I'm new to regular expressions, and I've spent the last two days working through online tutorials.  I think I understand some of the basics, but I'm at a loss trying to implement it with some data I have.

I have a few phrases:

Hello and welcome. My name is **Amanda**, how may I assist you today?
Hello and welcome.  My name is **Daniel L**, how may I assist you today?
Hello and welcome. My  name is  **John Livingston** , how may I assist you today?

Hello, my name is **Alyssa D**.. How can I help?
Hello, my name is **John**. How can I help?
Hello and welcome. My name is **Felicia F**., how may I assist you today?

Hello and welcome. My name is **Alex** how may I assist you today?
Hello and welcome. My name is **Alex P** how may I assist you today?

*I'm trying to retrieve the name that comes after some variation of "my name is".*

The problem is, sometimes there is a first name, name with initial, or first and last name.  Sometimes a period follows the name, sometime a comma, and sometimes nothing at all (except the word 'how', which could be the criteria).

How do I return just the full name?

Right now I have:
    [Mm][Yy]\s*[Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]\s*[Ii][Ss]\s*(\w+\s?\w*)

But it doesn't solve the problem
1.  It matches the whole phrase, not just the name
2.  In the case of 'Alex', it returns 'Alex How'

Any help would be appreciated.  I can't seem to make any progress on it!  Oh, I'm using R if that helps.

Comment: You could also try something like that `(?<=[Mm]y name is )(.*)(?=[hH]ow)`, though you'll have some extra punctuations here and there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses [strapplyc](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gsubfn/docs/strapply) in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) which extracts the capture group (the part matching the parenthesized portion of the regular expression).

```
# test data
Lines <- "Hello and welcome. My name is Amanda, how may I assist you today?
Hello and welcome. My name is Daniel L, how may I assist you today?
Hello and welcome. My name is John Livingston , how may I assist you today?
Hello, my name is Alyssa D.. How can I help?
Hello, my name is John. How can I help?
Hello and welcome. My name is Felicia F., how may I assist you today?
Hello and welcome. My name is Alex how may I assist you today?
Hello and welcome. My name is Alex P how may I assist you today?"
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines)) 

library(gsubfn)
strapply(L, "is ([A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z][a-z]*[.]?)?)", simplify = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Amanda"          "Daniel L"        "John Livingston" "Alyssa D."      
[5] "John"            "Felicia F."      "Alex"            "Alex P"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
is ([A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z][a-z]*[.]?)?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4zSIfWYsCKqnUyQb)

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but is gusbfn available for R v3.1.0?  I can't seem to install it.

Comment: The package has been available for nearly 10 years.  You can also use  the checkpoint package to download old versions but there is really no reason you should not be able to find gsubfn.